# wxWidgets ListView headers not showing

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

The headers of my ListCtrl are not showing up.

[image: Headers]

The entire bar that contains "Names" and "Values" in this image doesn't show up. I am using Codeblocks with the built in editor. Here is the code I used to add a column and dummy data and an image of the result:

```
wxListItem column;
column.SetText(_("Column 1"));
lvSongs->InsertColumn(0, column);

lvSongs->InsertItem(0, _("Song Title"));
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show how you created the `lvSongs`? If I understand the reference correctly, `InsertColumn` only takes effect if the `wxListCtrl` is of style `wxLC_REPORT`.

Comment: @ s.bandara I'm an idiot sometimes. Thank you. I forgot I switched it during testing and forgot to change it back before adding columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the style of the ListCtrl to wxLC_REPORT.